# Importing Styles with Microsoft Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a macro that runs across all files in a given folder. My `Normal.dotm` global template has the 3 font styles that the macro uses, however the macro stops because it repeatedly cannot find the style the macro calls upon. The easiest way would be to create a macro (or add to my current) that would automatically import these 3 styles from the global template to the active document.

Here's what I have so far:

```
Application.OrganizerCopy Source:= _
    "C:\Users\Inu\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Normal.dotm", _
    Destination:= _
    ActiveDocument _
    , Name:="DO_NOT_TRANSLATE", Object:=wdOrganizerObjectStyles
Application.OrganizerCopy Source:= _
    "C:\Users\Inu\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Normal.dotm", _
    Destination:= _
    ActiveDocument _
    , Name:="tw4winExternal", Object:=wdOrganizerObjectStyles
Application.OrganizerCopy Source:= _
    "C:\Users\Inu\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Normal.dotm", _
    Destination:= _
    ActiveDocument _
    , Name:="tw4winInternal", Object:=wdOrganizerObjectStyles
```

Any help at all with this? I have about a hundred files that need formatted, so importing individually is kind of out of the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you prepare a template with the styles you need, you could copy them all with the following command:

```
ActiveDocument.CopyStylesFromTemplate("C:\Temp\FullPathToTemplate.dotx")
```

Or did you already solve it in another way?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the original code is that the Destination parameter in `Application.OrganizerCopy` needs to be a string - the full path of destination document. I have tested the following code, and found it to work (Word 2013):

```
Sub test_style_copy()

Dim B_failed As Boolean

    Call add_style_from_Normal(ActiveDocument, "Orcamento", B_failed)

End Sub

' -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Sub add_style_from_Normal(destination_document As Word.Document, _
    style_name As String, B_fail As Boolean)

'  Adds the style "style_name" from the Normal template to the styles available
'  in the document <destination_document>

Dim B_Normal As Boolean
Dim copy_style As Variant
Dim normal_template As Word.Document

    B_fail = False

'  test if style "style_name" is already present in <destination_document>

    If style_exists(destination_document, style_name) Then Exit Sub

'  open the Normal template as a document, and test if style "style_name" is
'  present in Normal template

    Set normal_template = Application.NormalTemplate.OpenAsDocument
    B_Normal = style_exists(normal_template, style_name)
    normal_template.Close
    Set normal_template = Nothing

'  Style "style_name" not in Normal template, exit:

    If Not B_Normal Then
        MsgBox "Cannot copy style """ & style_name & """ from Normal.dotm to " & _
            vbCr & destination_document.Name & " :" & vbCr & vbCr & _
            "Style """ & style_name & """ does not exist in Normal.dotm", vbCritical
        B_fail = True
        Exit Sub
    End If

'  copy style "style_name" from Normal template to <destination_document>

    With Application
        .OrganizerCopy Source:=.NormalTemplate.FullName, _
            Destination:=destination_document.FullName, _
            Name:=style_name, Object:=wdOrganizerObjectStyles
    End With

'  check that style successfully copied:

    B_fail = Not style_exists(destination_document, style_name)
    If B_fail Then MsgBox "Copy of style " & style_name & " to " & _
        destination_document.Name & " failed", vbCritical

End Sub

' -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Function style_exists(test_document As Word.Document, style_name As String) As Boolean

'  style_exists = TRUE      Style "style_name" exists in document <test_document>
'               = FALSE     absent

    style_exists = False
    On Error Resume Next
    style_exists = test_document.Styles(style_name).NameLocal = style_name

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not copy the Styles over from the `Normal.dotm` to your file.

Process below:

> 1. Open Style Window 9Alt + Ctrl + Shift + S).
> 2. Select Manage Styles (At the bottom of the window, its the third icon from the left).
> 3. Select Import/Export.
> 4. Load your `Normal.dotm` in the Lleft side of the window.
> 5. Load your `SomeDoc.dotm` in the right side of the window.
> 6. Select the `Styles` which you wan to copy from the left window(in `Normal.dotm`).
> 7. Select `Copy`.

Those `Styles` have now been imported into your document. Be sure sure save the document as a Macro Enabled Template `.dotm`.

It should not be an issue after this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you are happy about the above solutions, but since the question is still listed as "unanswered", here the - somewhat simplified - code I am using for exactly this problem:

```
Sub Test()
    Const C_St1 = "style-1"
    Const C_St2 = "style-2"
    Const C_St3 = "style-3"

    A_Styles = Array(C_St1, C_St2, C_St3)
    Call VerifyExistenceOfStyles(A_Styles, V_Errors)
    Debug.Print V_Errors
End Sub

Sub VerifyExistenceOfStyles(A_Styles, Optional V_Errors)
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each V_Style In A_Styles
        If V_Style = "" Then
            'do nothing
        Else
            Err.Clear
            tmp = ActiveDocument.Styles(V_Style).Font.Size 'checking whether style exists
            V_ErrNumber = Err.Number
            If V_ErrNumber = 5941 Then Call AddMissingStyleFromTemplate(V_Style, V_Error) Else V_Error = ""
        End If
        V_Errors = V_Errors & IIf(V_Error = "", "", V_Error & vbCr)
    Next
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

Sub AddMissingStyleFromTemplate(V_Style, Optional V_Error)
    V_Template = ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.Path & Application.PathSeparator & ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.Name
    V_File = ActiveDocument.FullName

    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OrganizerCopy _
      Source:=V_Template, _
      Destination:=V_File, _
      Name:=V_Style, _
      Object:=wdOrganizerObjectStyles
    If Err.Number = 0 Then  'no error, style found in template
        V_Error = ""
    ElseIf Err.Number = 5608 Then 'is no style name
        V_Error = "|" & V_Style & "| is no valid style name, neither in the document nor in the template!"
    Else
        V_Error = "|" & V_Style & "| produces the unidentified error " & Err.Number
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

A small improvement to Olle Sjögren's solution above:

If all the styles you need are already in your normal.dotm, you can import them all with just this:

```
  ActiveDocument.CopyStylesFromTemplate (NormalTemplate.FullName)
```

This way the macro would not contain absolute paths, and thus may be shared with colleagues (who presumably have same styles already imported into their Normal.dotm)